# Magento Product Collection Limit via XML

Tags: magento, collections, limit, product

I've got a bestsellers module which I've written and it works great, however I want to be able to change the collection size it returns via the XML, rather than the php/phtml.

Something like this:

```
    <block type="catalog/product_list" name="bestsellers" limit="3" 
template="custom/bestsellers.phtml" />
```

or something like:

```
    <block type="catalog/product_list" name="bestsellers" 
template="custom/bestsellers.phtml">
         <action method="setLimit">3</action>
    </block>
```

Is this possible?

I'm currently changing the limit via the phtml with:

```
->setPageSize(3)
->setCurPage(1);
```

But that is hard coded and nasty, I need to be able to use my phtml file as template for many cases of the bestsellers module being called from anywhere with the XML + limit in the XML.

Thanks in advance if anyone can shed light on this!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The block `Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List` inherits from the `Varien_Object` class which contains the methods `getData()` and `setData()`, as well as the magic methods `get*()` and `set*()`.  These methods allow us to store (you guessed it) keyed-data within an object.

The `<action />` tags in the XML allows us to perform method calls on the block instances.  You're nearly there with your second example, but the syntax is:

```
<block type="catalog/product_list" name="bestsellers">
    <action method="setLimit"><value>3</value></action>
</block>
```

Which is equivalent to:

```
<block type="catalog/product_list" name="bestsellers">
    <action method="setData"><key>limit</key><value>3</value></action>
</block>
```

Which is roughly equivalent to:

```
$block = new Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List();
$block->setLimit(3);
```

With the data set in the object we can now access through the `getData()` or `get*()` methods by calling `$this->getLimit()` or `$this->getData('limit')` making our block code:

```
->setPageSize($this->getLimit())
->setCurPage(1);
```

You should probably perform a check for the existence of the `limit` data first and provide a default value if none is provided in the XML.

**Note**: The name of the children in the `<action />` tag don't matter.  It's the order of the arguments that's important.  We could just as well have called `<action method="setLimit"><foo>3</foo></action>` and it still would have worked.