# Limit number of products shown on homepage, list.phtml

Tags: magento, block, php

I am trying to limit the number of products from a certain category to 4 on my homepage.

The code I am trying to do this with is:

```
{{block type="catalog/product_list" column_count="4" category_id="13" template="catalog/product/list.phtml"}}
```

Here are some of the things I have tried:

```
num_products="4"
limit = 4, limit="4"
count = 4, count="4"
_productCollection="4"
_productsCount="4"
```

I have made a copy of list.phtml thinking there might be a way to change it in there, but was unable to find out a way.

At the very top pf list.phtml is this code:

```
<?php
    $_productCollection=$this->getLoadedProductCollection();
    $_helper = $this->helper('catalog/output');
?>
```

And under grid view there is this:

```
<?php $_collectionSize = $_productCollection->count() ?>
    <?php $_columnCount = $this->getColumnCount(); ?>
    <?php $i=0; foreach ($_productCollection as $_product): ?>
        <?php if ($i++%$_columnCount==0): ?>
```

Any ideas on to limit the products either within the block or the template file?

Answer (score 5):

The quicker is replace `column_count=4` by `is_homepage=1`

and in the phtml add this :

```
 <?php if($this->getIsHomepage() && $i==4) break; ?>
```

before this :

```
 <?php if ($i++%$_columnCount==0): ?>
```

Then you will have just 1 row on homepage (if 4 by row as I suppose) so total 4 products

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
 {{block type="catalog/product_list" limit="4" category_id="13" template="catalog/product/list.phtml"}}
```

See

- http://www.mcnab.co/blog/e-commerce/magento/magento-displaying-products-in-a-static-block/
- [Magento Product Collection Limit via XML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6959567/magento-product-collection-limit-via-xml)

Answer (score 2):

IN Magento ver. 1.9.0.1
i found a simple solution just add these line in list.phtml
just find the foreach loop it comes two times so need to add in both location.

```
<?php $i=0; ?>
<?php foreach ($_productCollection as $_product): 
if($i == 6) break;
$i++;
?>
```

i put it for 6 record you may change it to as you required.

thanks

Answer (score 1):

When I was facing this problem them i search to many sites but there is very less sites that make me understand of it..
    I edited it myself by doing these step to show FIXED NUMBER OF PRODUCTS FROM CERTAIN CATEGORIES follows as:-
    go to

```
1) app\design\frontend\default\<your theme>\template\catalog\product
   copy list.phtml and save as list_new.phtml
```

Now open list_new.phtml and search '' after ending the if loop insert this code

```
<?php if($i<=4): // for 4 product?>
```

and close after the list ended.

```
<?php endif // for 4 product?>
```

The code will look like this-

```
<?php if ($i++%$_columnCount==0): ?>
    <ul class="products-grid">
<?php endif ?>
<?php if($i<=4): // for 4 product?>
    <li class="item<?php if(($i-1)%$_columnCount==0): ?>"> 
        // some code here
     </li>
<?php endif // for 4 product?>
```

2) Now go to CMS>Pages>select home page >content> and copy this code (change your categy id here)

```
{{block type="catalog/product_list" name="product_list" category_id="<category id>" column_count="4"mode="grid" template="catalog/product/list_new.phtml"}}
```

Answer (score 1):

try this:
`$_productCollection=$this->getLoadedProductCollection();
$_productCollection->getSelect()->limit(5);`